# flake8 internal error in regular expression engine

Tags: python, django, docker-compose, raspberry-pi3, flake8

I'm trying to run flake8 on a docker django built like described here ([tutorial page](https://testdriven.io/blog/dockerizing-django-with-postgres-gunicorn-and-nginx/#production-dockerfile))

when building the docker image I get an error from flake8 which is run in an docker-compose file with like so

```
$ flake8 --ignore=E501,F401 .
```

```
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 125, in worker
result = (True, func(*args, **
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 48, in 
return list(map(*
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flake8/checker.py", line 666, in 
return checker.run_checks()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flake8/checker.py", line 598, in run_checks
self.run_ast_checks()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flake8/checker.py", line 495, in run_ast_checks
checker = self.run_check(plugin, tree=ast)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flake8/checker.py", line 426, in run_check
self.processor.keyword_arguments_for(                                                                                               File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flake8/processor.py", line 241, in keyword_arguments_for                                   arguments[param] = getattr(self, param)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flake8/processor.py", line 119, in file_tokens
self._file_tokens = list(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/tokenize.py", line 525, in _tokenize
pseudomatch = _compile(PseudoToken).match(line, pos)
RuntimeError: internal error in regular expression engine

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:                                                                                                                                                                                                        Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/flake8", line 8, in <module>
sys.exit(main())
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flake8/main/cli.py", line 18, in main
app.run(argv)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flake8/main/application.py", line 393, in run
self._run(argv)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flake8/main/application.py", line 381, in _run
self.run_checks()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flake8/main/application.py", line 300, in run_checks
self.file_checker_manager.run()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flake8/checker.py", line 329, in run
self.run_parallel()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flake8/checker.py", line 293, in run_parallel
for ret in pool_map:
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 448, in <genexpr>
return (item for chunk in result for item in chunk)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 865, in next
raise value
RuntimeError: internal error in regular expression engine
```

When I run flake8 with the --verbose flag, I get an error like this:

```
Fatal Python error: deletion of interned string failed
Python runtime state: initialized
KeyError: 'FILENAME_RE'
```

from the tokenizer.py

**Does anyone know how to solve this?**

Additional Data: 
running docker-compose v1.25.4 on an raspberry 3 with buster lite. 
Installed and compiled Python 3.8.2 from source with the flag --enableloadable-sqlite

Thanks for helping!

Comment: What happens if you just flake8 on one specific file?

Comment: Thanks! That helped a lot. flake8 can be run on any files and folders, but it's stuck/crashing when run on the virtualenv folder. When running like this: flake8 --exclude=./env, it runs perfectly. Anyone a clue why the venv is not working?

Comment: this looks like you have a version mismatch in your environment (such as the python you're using is 3.8.1 but you're running against 3.8.2)

Comment: in this case it's likely the first docker stage got cached and then the second stage was pulled resulting in a mismatch

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a very similar error profile when I had refactored and left a lot of data which formerly had been in the top of the project down in what became the package folder.  There were 33621 files including .venv, .nox, .pytest_cache, .coverage.

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 448, in <genexpr>
    return (item for chunk in result for item in chunk)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 868, in next
    raise value
IndexError: string index out of range
```

If you see a similar signature (the parallel processing engine being overwhelmed in some way and throwing an exception), you may want to review your project directory structure and make sure that you did not put this kind of data in your sources directories.